# python's yfinance ticker history not working

Tags: json, python-3.x, yfinance

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

> Blockquote

```
import yfinance as yf

tickerData = yf.Ticker("BTC-USD")

tickerDf = tickerData.history()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to upgrade yfinance to the latest version:

```
pip install yfinance -U
```